# Laravel RedirectIfAuthenticated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

i've problem, I'm trying to redirect users when they log in by role to their dashboard using middleware in laravel 6. But I'm stucked can't figure out where is the problem in this condition. Please help, thanks kindly.

Each role has this route **web.php**

```
Route::group([ 'as'=>'user.', 'prefix'=>'user', 'namespace'=>'User', 'middleware'=>['auth','user']],
    function(){
        Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

**Middleware** looks like

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 3 ) {
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }
```

**RedirectIfAuthenticated**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 1 ) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        }elseif (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 2) {
            return redirect()->route('author.dashboard');
        }elseif (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 3) {
            return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
        }else{
            
              return $next($request);
        }
```

And **LoginController**

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 1  ) {
            $this->redirectTo = route('admin.dashboard');
        }elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 2  ) {
            $this->redirectTo = route('author.dashboard');
        }elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 3  ) {
            $this->redirectTo = route('user.dashboard');
        } else {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }


        
    }
```

Comment: doing that in your constructor won't do anything ... the session has not started yet so `Auth::check` will always return `false` ... the `guest` middleware is the place for that

Comment: Can you help me to fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

Your first middleware check if the user is logged AND if he has the role 3.

Maybe change it for :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's working properly, I guess issue will be somewhere in RedirectIfAuthenticated or LoginController..